# entity framework 6 dbfunctions not available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I installed EF 6 in a DAL class library but I can get it work DbFunctions.TruncateTime, when I add the reference to System.Data.Entity and build the solution still appearing the message: The type or namespace name 'DbFunctions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?) .

Help... I need to compare dates !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the dbfunctions actually reside in EntityFramework.dll, add a reference to EntityFramework and you should be right.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

States in here the assembly is entityframework too.

Comment: Thank you, I added the reference to EF that was missing!