# Error when trying to AddMinutes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to convert a SQL statement over to LINQ-to-Entities and the adding of minutes is causing an error. Initially I'm trying to get the query to work
using LinqPad but I get an error

> DbFunctions does not exist in the namespace

when using the statement below. I'm getting basically the same error when I add this to my MVC controller as well. I've searched and can't find what if any reference I need to get the `Entity.DbFunctions` to work.

This is in my select to an anonymous object. I need to add some minutes, which is calculated by using a department offset and adding the time converted to minutes (1440 min in 24 hours).

```
ETD = System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes(f.ESTIMATED_OUT, f.OFFSET_DEP_TIME_MINS + (f.OFFSET_DEP_TIME_MINS/1440))
```

The first question is what I need to add to LinqPad and my MVC project to get the `Entity.DbFunctions` to work.

The second question is if this would be the correct way to get my calculated time or is there a better way?

```
var pastUtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-20);
var futureUtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2);

var result = (from f in API_FLIGHT
              where f.DEP_STATION == "ABC" 
                 && f.DEP_GATE == "44F" 
                 && f.ACTUAL_OUT == null
                 && f.ESTIMATED_OUT > pastUtcTime
                 && f.ESTIMATED_OUT < futureUtcTime
              orderby f.ESTIMATED_OUT
              select new
                    {
                        ETD=System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes(f.ESTIMATED_OUT, f.OFFSET_DEP_TIME_MINS + (f.OFFSET_DEP_TIME_MINS/1440)) 
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you are missing a reference, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448918/entity-framework-6-dbfunctions-not-available

Comment: In my MVC project I have the reference to EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer (even though I'm querying against Oracle). I added EntityFramework with NuGet when I first started this project.